How to customize destination of node_modules package js asset files
I'm trying to utilize https://www.npmjs.com/package/@newrelic/browser-agent in my react application, however a problem I'm running into is that the .js files that are generated during build time are placed in my root directory and not accessible like the rest of my asset files that are otherwise located in ./app-assets/
Here are a couple screenshots of the files in my root ./build/ directory and my manifest.json


I've been trying to create some sort of rule in my webpack config to both place these .js files in ./app-assets/ as well as ensure the manifest.json reflects that, but my webpack abilities are really lacking:
const newRelicRule = {
  test: /\.(js|jsx)$/i,
  include: [/node_modules\/(?!@newrelic\/browser-agent).*/],
  exclude: /node_modules/,
  use: [
    {
      loader: "file-loader",
      options: {
        outputPath: "./app-assets",
        publicPath: "/app-assets",
      },
    },
  ],
};

If anyone can help point me in the right direction, I'd greatly appreciate it!
